# Buttons not responding on a form shown while application is busy

Tags: delphi, button, delphi-7

I have a secondary form that shows up while doing some heavy processing in mainform.
I send messages to the secondary form (form2) about the progress of the processing - that works fine.
I want a button on form2 to cancel the processing by closing form2 and re-setting a global variable to false.  No buttons work on form2 if it is opened with form2.show (onclick and mousedown do nothing and the button does not move)
They do with form2.showmodal but that stops any processing in Mainform, it also stops seeing the normal window X to close Form2.

Comment: Put the long running stuff in a thread

Answer (score 3):

This happens because main thread is busy and cannot process window messages.

You should move heavy processing in a thread and use synchronization to control it.

An ugly hack would be calling

```
application.processmessages;
```

during heavy processing to force form message processing when main form is busy.

You'd better find an example with thread implementation and give a look at it.

Comment: Please do not recommend `application.processmessages`

Comment: `TApplication.ProcessMessages` is not a hack.

Comment: It's not a real hack, it's just bad coding. That's why I talk about "ugly hack".

Comment: Given the context of the question, you agree that using application.ProcessMessages in this case is bad coding. This doesn't mean it's always bad coding.

Comment: application.processmessages works - the button does not move but as I send each message from mainform it finds the onclick event.  Why is it ugly or bad coding?

Comment: @user3074340: if you don't understand the consequence of calling Application.ProcessMessages then you could encounter some nasty side effects down the road... As David pointed out as a comment under your question, the correct answer is to put long calculations in a separate thread...

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not advocate the usage of `Application.ProcessMessages`, I will show you an alternative with threading. In this example, I used the excellent [AsyncCalls](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/) threading library (made by Andreas Hausladen) because I like it's simplicity, an other excellent library is [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/) made by SO member Primož Gabrijelčič but it works only from Delphi version 2007 and up.

The example contains 2 forms, the main form with a `Calculate` button and a progress dialog that show a progress bar and a `Cancel` button.
The code is made in such a way you can reuse the progress dialog for other calculations since there are no hardcoded dependencies.

.dpr code:

```
program SO20424238;

uses
  Forms,
  u_frm_main in 'u_frm_main.pas' {Frm_main},
  u_dlg_progress in 'u_dlg_progress.pas' {ProgressDialog};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TFrm_main, Frm_main);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

main form :

```
unit u_frm_main;

interface

uses
  u_dlg_progress,
  AsyncCalls,
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Controls,
  Forms, StdCtrls;

const
  INT_MAX_CALCULATIONS = 100;

type
  TFrm_main = class(TForm)
    Btn_docalculate: TButton;
    procedure Btn_docalculateClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    CancelCalculation : Boolean;
    function SomeLongCalculation(OnProgress : TProgressEvent) : Integer;
    function ShowProgressDialog : TProgressDialog;
    procedure DoCalculate;
    procedure CancelEvent;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Async : IAsyncCall;
  end;

var
  Frm_main: TFrm_main;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFrm_main.CancelEvent;
begin
 // set cancelation flag
 CancelCalculation := True;
end;

procedure TFrm_main.Btn_docalculateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DoCalculate;
end;

function TFrm_main.ShowProgressDialog: TProgressDialog;
begin
 Result := TProgressDialog.Create(CancelEvent);
 Result.ProgressBar1.Max := INT_MAX_CALCULATIONS;
end;

function TFrm_main.SomeLongCalculation(OnProgress : TProgressEvent) : Integer;

var
  Index : Integer;

begin
 // BEWARE - this function runs in a different thread
 // *any* call to the VCL/GUI/shared variables must happen in the main (GUI) thread 
 // AsyncCalls make this easy by providing the EnterMainThread and LeaveMainThread functions
 for Index := 0 to INT_MAX_CALCULATIONS do
  begin
   Sleep(100); // replace this line with the actual calculation
   // now check if the user has canceled, check this in the main thread
   EnterMainThread;
   try
    if CancelCalculation then
     begin
      // notify progress window we are done
      if Assigned(OnProgress) then
       OnProgress(INT_MAX_CALCULATIONS);
      // exit calculation loop
      Break;
     end
    else
    // report actual progress
    if Assigned(OnProgress) then
     OnProgress(Index);
   finally
    LeaveMainThread;
   end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrm_main.DoCalculate;

var
  ProgressDialog : TProgressDialog;

begin
 // create our progress dialog
 ProgressDialog := ShowProgressDialog;
 // reset cancelation flag
 CancelCalculation := False;
 // fire up calculation on a separate thread and hook up OnProgress function of our Progress dialog
 Async := TAsyncCalls.Invoke<TProgressEvent>(SomeLongCalculation, ProgressDialog.OnProgress);
 // show progress dialog, this will block all other forms from user input
 ProgressDialog.ShowModal;
end;

procedure TFrm_main.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if Assigned(Async) then
  Async.Forget;
end;

end.
```

main form dfm:

```
object Frm_main: TFrm_main
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Threading example'
  ClientHeight = 82
  ClientWidth = 273
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Btn_docalculate: TButton
    Left = 92
    Top = 28
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Calculate!'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Btn_docalculateClick
  end
end
```

progress dialog:

```
unit u_dlg_progress;

interface

uses
  AsyncCalls,
  SysUtils,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  Dialogs,
  StdCtrls,
  ComCtrls,
  Classes;

type
  TCancelEvent = procedure of object;

  TProgressEvent = procedure(Value : Integer) of object;

  TProgressDialog = class(TForm)
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    Btn_cancel: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure Btn_cancelClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FCancelEvent : TCancelEvent;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure OnProgress(Value : Integer);
    constructor Create(CancelEvent : TCancelEvent);
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TProgressDialog }

procedure TProgressDialog.Btn_cancelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if Assigned(FCancelEvent) then
  FCancelEvent;
end;

procedure TProgressDialog.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 // make sure our dialog is freed after use
 Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TProgressDialog.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 // reset progress bar
 ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
end;

procedure TProgressDialog.OnProgress(Value: Integer);
begin
 if Value >= ProgressBar1.Max then
  Close;
 ProgressBar1.Position := Value;
 Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Value);
end;

constructor TProgressDialog.Create(CancelEvent: TCancelEvent);
begin
 inherited Create(nil);
 FCancelEvent := CancelEvent;
end;

end.
```

progress dialog dfm:

```
object ProgressDialog: TProgressDialog
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  BorderIcons = []
  BorderStyle = bsDialog
  Caption = 'ProgressDialog'
  ClientHeight = 101
  ClientWidth = 364
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 18
    Top = 55
    Width = 77
    Height = 26
    Caption = 'Label1'
  end
  object ProgressBar1: TProgressBar
    Left = 8
    Top = 16
    Width = 341
    Height = 25
    Smooth = True
    MarqueeInterval = 1
    Step = 1
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Btn_cancel: TButton
    Left = 136
    Top = 59
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Cancel = True
    Caption = '&Cancel'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Btn_cancelClick
  end
end
```